# correctly handling restart of an android service

Tags: android, service

I am implementing a android service that is connected to an internet server. The service is creating a session when the service starts, periodically sends messages to the server and finally removes the session from the server when the service is closed.

Starting and stopping the service from an application works fine and onCreate, onStartCommand and onDestroy() are called. I would prefer if the service would be able to run without the connection to the UI/activity. This to be able to start at boot.

However, if I close the activity from the android launcher only onDestroy on the activity is called, not to the service. As I use START_STICKY the system restarts the service, once again calling onCreate, onStartCommand.

So how do I detect that the service is closed the first time so I can send my "logout" to my server? Or alternative detect a restart so I don't "login" once again?

I tried to use a static Boolean to keep track if the service was started (user logged in) or not, but it seems to be reset to false once the service is restarted

Answer (score 0):

If code inside `onCreate` is executing, the service *IS* running, `&& !sIsServiceRunning` is useless. `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called, system might just kill the process without alerting the service about it.

Comment: sIsServiceRunning is primary used to check if the service is running from outside (the activity). The line "if (intent != null && !sIsServiceRunning)" was a start of a workaround to not have the system send a login message to the server if it was restarted.

Comment: @Sunkas The Only ways to communicate with a service from activity is to share an IBinder, or use an Intent BroadCast. All explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Comment: I guess I could use a IBinder to communicate that onDestroy was called in the activity and call the code I normally place in onDestroy in the service.